# Rails 3: copy attributes and values from one template model to a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a set of records that I want each users to start with in item_templates table. And then, in items table, I have user_id and each item. So, basically the schema looks like;

item_templates table:

- item_code
- item_name
- ... a bunch of other attributes

items table:

- user_id
- item_code
- item_name
- ... a bunch of other attributes

Each time a new user is created, I want to copy items in the template for that user in items table. Is there any simple way to do it avoiding coding all the attributes to copy from item_templates to items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
item.update_attributes(template.attributes)
```